# Can video compositions for 2 participants be dual channel?

Tags: twilio, composition, audio-channels

I have a video group room with 2 participants and I request a video composition at the end.

Can the audio from each participant be written to a separate channel (dual channel) so they can be extracted and analyzed separately?

Comment: Were you able to do this?

Comment: No. I ended up producing two compositions - with both participants included (for alignment) but only one audio included.